# Kobo reader: how to open the root folder

Tags: ebook

I'm trying to install Koreader, the alternative PDF-reader on my Kobo Aura One. Installation instructions say I have to install it in the root directory. When I connect the Kobo via USB to my Mac, I see a folder with all the books. Copying to that folder doesn't result in installation it seems.

**How can I copy files to the root of a Kobo reader?**

Answer (score 3):

Basically [Kobo is running a GNU/Linux system](https://github.com/kobolabs/Kobo-Reader) with armhf architecture (but it's a kernel 2.6 with system-V style boot, not systemd, etc), probably built using [Linaro](https://www.linaro.org/downloads/). Normally when you connect and disconnect to it, or at boot, it will scan for the presence of a specific file called `KoboRoot.tgz` in the "hidden" directory `.kobo`, on the data (books) filesystem exported by USB gadget. Once you disconnect the Kobo, it will uncompress this tar archive to `/`. If the archive contains new files and directories, those files and directories will be added. If it contains already existing files, it will overwrite those files.

To be explicit: you cannot access directly the root directory. You can make the Kobo itself copy archived files there. Or you could hack your Kobo. For exemple you could add a telnet or ftp daemon feature (because they are already provided by busybox, ssh is not) accessible with the activation of an additional USB ethernet gadget driver. You would then have a direct access.

This `KoboRoot.tgz` isn't a magic backdoor. It's the way Kobo is implementing, very openly, its own upgrades: when Kobo Desktop gets a new update (eg: https://download.kobobooks.com/firmwares/kobo6/Dec2019/kobo-update-4.19.14123.zip), it leaves a new `KoboRoot.tgz` in `.kobo`. There's also a "firmware" upgrade part (ie: a new kernel, along with [U-Boot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot) etc. ). You really shouldn't mess with this part.

As you can guess it's very easy to brick your Kobo (normally the full reset/erase-everything will still work). Eg, replace by mistake `/etc/init.d/rcS` with a non-executable file and it won't boot anymore. You should have some Linux knowledges when doing this. If creating yourself the `KoboRoot.tgz` file, it should be preferably archived using Linux, or there might be issues with the access rights. Anyway Mac is still a better choice than Windows for this.

Further documentation (all on https://www.mobileread.com/). Beware it could be obsolete and sometimes it applies only to specific Kobo hardware/firmware versions. Aura ONE appears to be [Mark 6](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Kobo_Firmware_Releases#Mark_6).

- [Koreader running on Kobos (all of them, hopefully!)](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=216960)
- [How to install ksm and koreader](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=294016)

Comment: Thanks! I will try this from an Ubuntu laptop.